One-way domination in bipartite regular graphs
Let $G=(U,V,E)$ be a regular bipartite graph of degree $d>0$, with $|U|=|V|=n$. Let us say that a subset $S\subseteq U$ dominates $V$ if every vertex of $V$ is adjacent to at least one vertex in $S$.
I am interested in upper bounding the minimum size of such a "one-way" dominating set $S$, depending on the degree $d$. In particular, is the size of $S$ bounded by a constant when (say) $d=n/2$ or $d=n/3$, and more generally when $d=O(n)$? Otherwise, is it bounded by a function growing more slowly than $\log(n)$?

The best bound I could come up with was $(1+\varepsilon)\frac{n\log n}d$. Which for constant $n/d$ is $O(\log n)$, I do believe this to be best possible. One can show that w.h.p. in $G(2n,d/n)\cap G$ every set $S\subset U$ of size $\ll \frac{n\log n}{d}$ does not cover. If you could prove the same for the configuration model then you would show that this is best possible. If you want I can turn it into an answer, but I wouldn't do the calculations for the configuration model since I have little to no experience with it

@BrunoAndrades This could have been a valid answer, indeed. Caduk's answer has the additional advantage that it refers to a published answer to an equivalent question. Thanks anyway!

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the hypergraph defined on the ground set $U$ and with the the neighborhoods of vertices of $V$ as hyperedges. The hypergraph $\mathcal{H}$ is $d$-regular and $d$-uniform. Reciprocally, from a $d$-regular and $d$-uniform hypergraph, we get back a bipartite graph, so your problem is equivalent to bound the tranversal number of $\mathcal{H}$.
In the following paper, they show that it is bounded by $\left(\frac{1+\log{d}}{d}\right)n$, and that this bound is asymptotically tight:
Henning, Michael A.; Yeo, Anders, Transversals in regular uniform hypergraphs, J. Graph Theory 105, No. 3, 468-485 (2024). ZBL1531.05184.
For constant $\frac{n}{d}$, this gives a $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ growth.

Very informative, this answers the question!
